# What prevented Ego from saving himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

The initial plan of Guardians was to keep Ego distracted while bomb explodes.

> Groot? If you can hear me, hurry up! I'm not sure how long Quill can keep him distracted!

But, they failed at keeping him distracted until the end.

When Ego noticed the bomb, he had 25 seconds to stop the bomb from exploding near his brain. But, all he did was cry helplessly:

> No, we need to stop it. Stop! Stop!! Listen to me!!!
>   You are a god. If you kill me... you'll be just like everybody else.

Yes, Peter was holding him, but in reality he was just holding his human form. The whole planet was at Ego's command. He could have simply thrown the bomb into outer space or create a protective shell around brain (there was a reason why Rocket needed to create a hole in the protective shell around brain) or change the mechanism of bomb itself (if he could give tumor to Peter's mother, he could certainly do this). If Peter's hold was that much distracting, he could have simply destroyed his human form.

What prevented him from saving himself?

Comment: Speed, maybe? Do we have any evidence in the movie of a planet capable of reshaping itself in a bunch of seconds?

Comment: @motoDrizzt In [this video](https://youtu.be/QsyHgOgpTjA), he reconstructed his human form quickly after being shot. Also, during the last fight, his tentacles were coming out and fighting Guardians..

Comment: I think the fact that he died was what prevented him from saving himself.

Answer (score 1):

The bomb was directly on his brain, so he couldn't create a protective shell between the bomb and his brain, because there was no space there. Reorganizing the material within the detonator probably takes time. The tentacles could've stopped it, but again, time, and the bomb was on his brain. Could've possibly stabbed himself in the process.